# Updating the color of a row in DataGrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to set the color of the rows of a DataGrid based on the value of a bindings.
I used the following solution:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

This works when the rows are loaded, but if I change the value of the binding the row color doesn't get updated accordingly.
The same property is binded to an attribute of a single column (of the same datagrid) and that does work correctly

```
...
<CheckBox ... IsEnabled="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
...
```

Is it because the style is applied only once ?
I cannot use Triggers as it seems that they don't work in Silverlight. Any other idea ? Do I have to apply the background to every single column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Silverlight 5? Binding within style property setters is only available in [Silverlight 5](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/05/binding-on-style-setter-in-silverlight.html)

Comment: Unfortunately we are stuck with Silverlight 4 for the time being. Anyway, good to know that it should work in Silverlight 5. Thanks !